# Creating a 3D grid using X,Y,Z coordinates at cell centers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a question, I have been given x,y,z coordinate values at cell centers of a grid. I would like to create structured grid using these cell center coordinates. 
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Look into `np.meshgrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grid is regular:

1. You have calculate `dx = x[i+1]-x[i]`, `dy = y[i+1]-y[i]`, `dz = z[i+1]-z[i]`.
2. Then calculate new arrays of points:
   `x1[i] = x[i]-dx/2`, `y1[i] = y[i]-dy/2`, `z1[i] = z[i]-dz/2`.

If mesh is irregular you have to do the same but `dx,dy,dz` you have to define for every grid cell.